# Solve limit when $x\to \infty$ of $\ln$ expression

Tags: limits

I have this limit: $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}x[\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)]$

Now I have tried to transform the expression to something like this:
$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}[\ln(\frac{x+1}{x})^x]$

I was thinking of making this look like the limit of number e, but doesn't look like it, I'm stuck. I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Check your last expression, it should be $ln((\frac{x+1}{1})^x)$. This evaluates to a well known expression. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why the denominator has become 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track. Note that, as $x\to +\infty$,
$$\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^x=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\to e$$
(as a reference see for example [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Calculus)).

Comment: So you are saying I can do this: $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}[\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})^x]$, than  $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}ln[\(1+\frac{1}{x})^x]$, than: $ln\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}[\(1+\frac{1}{x})^x]$, and in the end ln(e)=1. Is that correct

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln((x+1)/x)=\ln(1+1/x)\rightarrow 0$, just write this as $\frac{\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)}{1/x}$ and apply l'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

> I though it might be instructive to provided a "HINT" so that evaluation of the limit relies on pre-calculus tools only.

**HINT:**

Use the inequalities

$$\frac1{x+1}\le \log\left(1+\frac1x\right)\le \frac1x$$

(See [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263)), multiply by $x$, and apply the squeeze theorem.